# C# create two arrays for the same type

Tags: c#, .net

Our senior dev is out of the office and I need some help with to create two arrays for the same node. Below is an example of what I need in XML format;

```
<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers>
    <numberOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <Qualifier>Person</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
    </numberOfQualifiers>
    <numberOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Qualifier>User1</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Qualifier>User2</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
    </numberOfQualifiers>
</RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers>
```

However what I am getting is this;

```
<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers>
    <numberOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <Qualifier>Person</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Qualifier>User1</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
        <nbrOfQualifiers>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <Qualifier>User2</Qualifier>
        </nbrOfQualifiers>
    </numberOfQualifiers>
</RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers>
```

Below is my code;

```
public static RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers ServicesRequest(string person, List<string> users)
{
    RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers services = new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers();
    List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers> qualifier = new List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers>();
    qualifier.Add(new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers { Qualifier = 2, Value = person });           

    foreach (var userNo in users)
    {
        qualifier.Add(new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers { Qualifier = 3, Value = userNo });                    
    }                

    services.numberOfQualifiers = qualifier.ToArray(); 

    return services;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Dave

Comment: Is the grouping by `Value`?

Comment: There is no direct XML generation in code sample you've posted. Obviously it it hidden somewhere in `RequestService*` classes, so it is impossible to help you without seeing these sources. I suspect "wait until your senior dev will return and ask him" will be most suitable answer.

Comment: vzwick yes grouping is by value

Comment: It seems to me that you have to instantiate a second List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers> and add your Qualifier = 3 items to it.

Comment: Are you getting back an array of numberOfQualifiers or just a singular?   The underlining code may be doing a SelectMany() to get a one dimensional array nbrOfQualifiers[] or returning a two dimensional array numberOfQualifiers[nbrOfQualifiers][].  The solution will be different.

Comment: @jdweng I'm getting back a singular

Comment: Your code cannot work unless the ServicesRequest is called multiple times.  The method ServicesRequest is getting only one person (the qualifier) and a list of users.  The xml you expect to get has multiple persons and users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your object/model should be something like this:

```
public class nbrOfQualifiers
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Qualifier { get; set; }
}

public class RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers
{
    public List<List<nbrOfQualifiers>> numberOfQualifiers { get; set; } // note that I have
                                                                        // List<List<T>>
}
```

Here is your object

```
var foo = new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers()
{
    numberOfQualifiers = new List<List<nbrOfQualifiers>>()
    {
        new List<nbrOfQualifiers>()
        {
            new nbrOfQualifiers(){ Value = 2, Qualifier = "Person"},
        },
        new List<nbrOfQualifiers>()
        {
            new nbrOfQualifiers(){ Value = 3, Qualifier = "User1"},
            new nbrOfQualifiers(){ Value = 4, Qualifier = "User2"},
        }
    }
};
```

If you serialize the above object into XML, it should give you your expected result.

> The key is that you need to use a `List<List<T>>` for your `numberOfQualifiers`.

Answer (score 0):

try using nested lists like so...

```
public static RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers ServicesRequest(string person, List<string> users)
{
    var services = new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiers();
    var qualifier = new List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers>();
    qualifier.Add(new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers { Qualifier = 2, Value = person });
    // numberOfQualifiers should be of Type List<List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers>>
    services.numberOfQualifiers.Add(qualifier.ToArray());

    qualifier = new List<RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers>();
    foreach (var userNo in users)
    {
        qualifier.Add(new RequestServiceNumberOfQualifiersNbrOfQualifiers { Qualifier = 3, Value = userNo });
    }                

    services.numberOfQualifiers.Add(qualifier.ToArray());

    return services;
}
```